# gsutil: ImportError: No module named google

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

As of Friday 11th of February, 2016, gsutil has suddenly stopped working. I run nightly backups using gsutil, and prior to executing I perform a `gcloud components update`.

```
$ gsutil --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/IRUser/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/home/IRUser/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 9, in <module>
    import setup
  File "/home/IRUser/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/setup.py", line 41, in <module>
    reload(google)
ImportError: No module named google
```

If I manually `pip install google`, gsutil works fine again. However, I question that this somehow wasn't performed by `gcloud components update`.

**My question:** Isn't `gcloud components update` supposed to take care of any such dependencies?

I'm on CentOS 7.

Comment: You shouldn't need to pip install google. In fact I would pip uninstall google if you don't explicitly need it.
It's probably that your gcloud installation is corrupt somehow and missing the included google library. I would reinstall it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been reported https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=538

"google" package was included in previous releases of cloud sdk, but it is no longer needed.

On python installations (which have protobuf installed) "google" package is auto-imported on the startup the reload of existing google package can fail.

By installing it "google" with pip you made reload stop complaining about the module, even though it is not used.

Alternatively you can apply patches suggested in the above issue log.

Comment: installing google with pip does not make this error go away if there is a different version of python in your path. Google Cloud SDK 146.0.0

Comment: This issue should have been resolved some time ago. Would you mind opening a new issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187171&template=0, showing your error stacktrace?